# what is difference between http.get( ) method and var request = require('request')

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, npm, node-modules

I am new to the node JS ,In the nodeJS exercise no.8 of learnyounode ,my solution produces the same require result.I am confused when to use http.get and Request

**goal**: 
Write a program that performs an HTTP GET request to a URL provided to you
  as the first command-line argument. Collect all data from the server (not
  just the first "data" event) and then write two lines to the console
  (stdout).

The first line you write should just be an integer representing the number
  of characters received from the server. The second line should contain the
  complete String of characters sent by the server.

**official solution**

```
var http = require('http')
var bl = require('bl')

http.get(process.argv[2], function (response) {
    response.pipe(bl(function (err, data) {
        if (err)
            return console.error(err)
        data = data.toString()
        console.log(data.length)
        console.log(data)
    }))
})
```

**my solution**

```
var request=require('request')
request(process.argv[2],function(err,response,body){
console.log(body.length);
console.log(body);
})
```

Comment: there are many http tools out there, request is just another one, http comes packed within node.js, another one is for example [Axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios)

Comment: request is a third-party library, the http module is built in.

Comment: yeah so it is good practice to use request in place of http.get() in some situations?

Comment: I wouldn't say it is good practice... But if it eases your developements sure. Thing is that you are learning NodeJS, you shouldn't learn just yet thrid party libraries. Get used to the basics first is what I'd recommend. Just like learning jQuery before javascript is not a good idea.

Comment: It depends entirely on your requirements. E.g. `request` "follows redirects by default" which `http.get` does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [nodeJS documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_options_callback):

> Since most requests are GET requests without bodies, Node.js provides
>   this convenience method. The only difference between this method and
>   http.request() is that it sets the method to GET and calls req.end()
>   automatically. Note that response data must be consumed in the
>   callback for reasons stated in http.ClientRequest section.

So, what exactly that means, is that you could do it your way without any problem. But `request` is not a module shipped with node itself, it is a module to make http(s) requests easier on the developers. So I'm guessing here, that you are learning NodeJS and not using third-parties should be the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with *request* but it's seems like it's just a [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) that wraps the functionality of the standard library. You can use both but I would suggest reading through the documentation of [http.get](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_options_callback) and [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) and if you find the standard library function (http.get) sufficient for your needs I don' t see a reason you should use the request package.